# How to use Lambda expression to format date

Tags: c#

New to Lambda. This question is specifically on Lambda expression to manipulate date formatting. The below code used to get all the reminders from scheduler system:

```
MyReminders = ScheduledActionService.GetActions().Where(
    a => a.BeginTime.Date == Today
);
```

1. It is possible to change the date format before returning the result set.

   ```
   .where (
       a => a.BeginTime.Date == Today).Select(
           //the date and format
           BeginTime.date.ToString("d", new cultureInfo("zh-CN")) 
   )
   ```
2. Change the Date format as follows but will this work in the lambda expression?

   ```
   BeginTime.Date.ToString("d",new cultureInfo("zh-CN"),
   ```

Thanks and appreciate your help.

------------ Update :

I tried these two methods. There is no result being displayed in the ListBox :

This scheduler system is for windows phone 7. This reminder object contains Following properties:
1) BeginTime,2) ExpirationTime,3) Title,4) Content,5) isSchedule and ohers

After retrieving, I need to DataBind it to a ListBox .  ReminderListBox.ItemsSource = MyReminders;

1)  var czech = new CultureInfo("zh-CN");

```
        var MyReminders = ScheduledActionService.GetActions<Reminder>()
            .Where(a => a.BeginTime.Date == Today)
            .Select(a =>
            new
            {
             Begindate = a.BeginTime.Date.ToString("d", czech),
             Title = a.Title,
             Content = a.Content
            });
```

2) var czech = new CultureInfo("zh-CN");
     var MyReminders = ScheduledActionService.GetActions()
      .Where(a => a.BeginTime.Date == Today)
      .Select(a => a.BeginTime.Date.ToString("d", czech));

```
   < ListBox Name="ReminderListBox" > 
        < ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            < DataTemplate>
            < Grid Background="Transparent" Margin="0,0,0,30">

            < StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                 < TextBlock FontSize="23" Text="{Binding Title}"/ >

                  < TextBlock FontSize="23"  Text="{Binding Content}" />

                    < StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                       < TextBlock Text="begin "/>
                      < TextBlock x:Name="txtDate" Text="{Binding BeginTime}" />
                      < /StackPanel>

                     < StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                       < TextBlock Text="expiration "/>
                       < TextBlock Text="{Binding ExpirationTime}"/>
                        < /StackPanel>
                    < StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                      < TextBlock Text="recurrence "/>
                     < TextBlock Text="{Binding RecurrenceType}" />
                    < /StackPanel>
                       < StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                       < TextBlock Text="is scheduled? "/>
                         < TextBlock Text="{Binding IsScheduled}"/>

                          < /StackPanel>

                                     < /StackPanel>

                                <  /Grid>
                             < /DataTemplate>
                         < /ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                     < /ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can *select* the items that pass your predicate in `Where`, you can *project* those into a different sequence of types, but you can (should) not *change* the items in the sequence.

```
var results = yourSequence.Where(yourPredicate)
                          .Select(item => item.BeginDate.ToString("yourformat"));
```

In this example, the lambda is a `Func<YourType, string>`, where `YourType` is the type of the elements in the sequence and `string` is the output of the expression. That is to say it takes the input (`YourType`) on the left side `item =>` and produces the output (`string`) on the right `item.BeginDate.ToString()`.

This will give you an `IEnumerable<string>` consisting of the `BeginDate` values in the string format of your choice. Alternately, you could project into an another type

```
var results = yourSequence.Select(item => 
           new 
           { 
               DateString = item.BeginDate.ToString("yourformat"),
               Foo = item.Foo,
               Bar = item.Bar
           });
```

This will give you an `IEnumerable<AnonymousType>` that you can then loop over and access the `DateString`, `Foo`, and `Bar` properties. And, of course, the lambda will represent a `Func<YourType, AnonymousType>`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you quite understand what a lambda is. At it's heart, a lambda is exactly the same as (in your case)

```
delegate bool FilterMyObject(MyObject)

bool WhereToday(MyObject obj) {
  return obj.BeginTime.Date == Today
}

....

 MyReminders = ScheduledActionService.GetActions().Where(new FilterMyObject(whereToday))
```

it will compile down to something very similar (except it will use the generic delegate Func).

Now if you are using Linq2Sql or something else where the parameter is of type `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` there is an added step where the person who implemented that where method has a chance to examine what you're trying to do (and usually optimize it).

To answer your question, you probably want

```
var czech = new CultureInfo("zh-CN");
var MyReminders = ScheduledActionService.GetActions()
                .Where(a => a.BeginTime.Date == Today);
                .Select(a => a.BeginTime.Date.ToString("d",czech)
                .ToArray();
```

Which will output an array of formatted strings